# Select the maximum rows of sorted subgroups

Tags: postgresql, datetime, max, truncate, distinct-on

Using PostgreSQL 11, I have a table containing a DAY and MONTH_TO_DAY entry for each day of every month. I would like to select the most recent MONTH_TO_DAY entry for each account.
My table is:

```
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
|id    |account     |code          |interval    |timestamp                 |
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
|387276|ALPBls6EsP  |52            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-09-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387275|ALPBls6EsP  |52            |DAY         |2020-09-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387272|YkON8lk8A8  |25            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-09-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387271|YkON8lk8A8  |25            |DAY         |2020-08-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387273|ALPBls6EsP  |32            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-08-31 01:05:00.000000|
|387274|ALPBls6EsP  |32            |DAY         |2020-08-31 01:05:00.000000|
|387272|ALPBls6EsP  |27            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-08-30 01:05:00.000000|
|387271|ALPBls6EsP  |27            |DAY         |2020-08-30 01:05:00.000000|
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
```

If it helps, the entries are always in descending order timewise.

In a query asking for all accounts, since the 31st is the last day of 08 and the 1st is the most recent entry of 09, my expected output would be

```
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
|id    |account     |code          |interval    |timestamp                 |
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
|387276|ALPBls6EsP  |52            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-09-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387272|YkON8lk8A8  |25            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-09-01 01:05:00.000000|
|387273|ALPBls6EsP  |32            |MONTH_TO_DAY|2020-08-31 01:05:00.000000|
+------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------------------+
```

I was thinking I'd like to group entries by month (truncate the dd/hh/ss), and then select the row with the maximum timestamp in each group. I can get the right rows with this but I can't figure out how to get any of the other fields.

```
SELECT max(timestamp) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', mytable.timestamp);
```

I also thought I could use distinct on something like the below, but I'm not too familiar with distinct on or date_trunc and I can't figure out how to use them together.

```
SELECT distinct on (timestamp)
    *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', mytable.timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want `distinct on`, but you want to apply it to the `account`:

```
select distinct on (account) *
  from mytable
 where interval = 'MONTH_TO_DAY'
 order by account, timestamp desc;
```

If you want the latest by `account` by `month`, then this should work:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('month', timestamp), account) *
  from mytable
 where interval = 'MONTH_TO_DAY'
 order by date_trunc('month', timestamp), account, timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this only gives the most recent row per account? Whereas I need the most recent row per account, per month.

Comment: @blueberryscones That is exactly what your question asks at the top.  If you want it by month, as well, then add `date_trunc('month', timestamp)` to the `distinct on`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as clear as possible with the question. Thanks for the answer. How would I add date_trunc to the distinct on? Creating

`select distinct on (account_code, date_trunc('month', timestamp)) *
  from network_usage
  where network_usage.interval = 'MONTH_TO_DAY'
  order by account_code, timestamp desc`

Gives me the error I've been getting trying to combine these all along, distinct on expressions must match initial order by expressions. Putting date_trunc into the order by as well does not fix it. Apologies for the code formatting, comment formatting seems different.

Comment: @blueberryscones You have to include the `date_trunc('month', timestamp)` to the `order by`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @blueberryscones  Don't sound so surprised.  It shakes my confidence.  :-)